# What stops an additional layer from destructively adding to the previous layers in an Adaboost?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, adaboost

Algorithmic representation of Discrete [Adaboost](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/boost.pdf) is:

1. Start with weights $w_i = 1/N, i = 1, .. N$
2. Repeat for $m = 1,...,M$

   - Fit the classifier $f_m(x)  \in \{-1,1\}$ using weights $w_i$ on the training data
   - Compute $err_m = E_w[1_{(y \neq f_m(x))}], c_m = log((1-err_m)/err_m)$
   - Set $w_i \gets w_i*exp[(c_m*1_{(y \neq f_m(x))}], i = 1,2,...N$ and renormalize so that $\Sigma_iw_i = 1$
3. Output the classifier $sign[\Sigma_{m=1}^{M}c_mf_m(x)]$

As we can see lower the number of misclassifications higher the weight assigned to the misclassified sample in the subsequent classifier. So let us assume there is just one misclassified sample left after a layer, what makes sure that the result of the additional classifier added wont sacrifice two low weighted, correctly classified, samples from previous layers at the expense of classifying the one heavy weighted misclassified (so far) candidate?